# Navigation bar disappears when show segue is executed from one ViewController to another?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a ViewController with a tableView in it and when I tap on a cell it performs a segue(show) from that view controller to another viewController with a navigationController embed in it. I have the segue going directly to the ViewController not the navigationController. But when the segue executes, it brings me to the second viewController but the navigation bar that used to be there is gone. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your second view controller is embedded in the navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segue must be connected to the SecondViewController's NavigationController. Remake your segue connection from your FirstViewController to SecondViewController's NavigationContoller.